# c++ How to get acces of function that is in parent class?

Tags: c++, class, vector

I have class **Books** and child class **BookClient**.

In class **Books** their is function that calculates age of book:

```
int age()
{return 2017 - getage();}
```

I want function that prints books that are **>5 age** and are form certain publisher.

I am using **range-based** for loop to access the **vec.**

```
vector <BookClient> vec;

void printageover5(string publisher)
{
    for (const auto& cs : vec)
    if (cs.age() > 5 && getpublisher()==publisher)
    {
        ..........
    }
}

int main()
{
printageover("Amazon");
}
```

getpublisher() is member of class Book Client

And their is the error:

```
the object has type qualifiers that are not compatible with the member function
 object type is: const  Books
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `age` is not a `const` member function, so you cannot call it on a `const` reference.

Change the declaration to

```
int age() const { return 2017 - getage(); }
```

and make sure that `getage()` member function is also declared `const`.

```
int getage() const { ... }
```

**Note:** If you would like your code to be correct for longer than one year, hard-coding the current year is not a good idea.